# Safari 8 browser not triggering button click event

Tags: browser, compatibility

Safari 8 browser not triggering button click event. I am working on a eCommerce tool named AspdotnetStorefront. Here the html contents are generated dynamically in c# code.

**Eg code**

```
lnkAddVariant.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("return VariantShowInsertForm('{0}');", productID);
```

this onclick event is not triggered in safari 8. in all previous safari browsers it is working fine.